# Spark Array<String> of length 3 to Array<String> of length one

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark

I need to tokenize author names the format "Last, F" as one token. Spark tokenizer gives me array length three ['last, , f'].

I tried regexing the input data with quotes around the entire field. I researched converting to a an array of length one and found nothing.

```scala
tokenizer.setInputCol("authorName").setOutputCol("authorNameTokens")
val dfTokens = tokenizer.transform(df.na.fill(Map("authorName" -> "")))
```

Expected result:
['last, f'] -> Array [String] of length 1

Actual result:
['last, ,f'] -> Array [String] of length 3

Comment: Why do You need `Tokenizer` in this case ? You are not really tokenizing anything but just lowercasing it as far as I understand.

Comment: Could you show how the input is and how the output should look like?

Comment: I don't strictly need the Tokenizer, but I am doing more that lowercasing.

Comment: Input: `"Last, F"`
Output: `["last, f"]`

Spark doesn't seem to allow Array[String] of length 1